# UPDATE query joining table and subselect in ACCESS

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to update a field of my table1 using the following code but I receive the following error message:3073 operation must use an updateable query.

```sql
UPDATE table1 a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(somevalue) AS Total,ID 
FROM ReadsPNPA GROUP BY ID) b 
ON a.ID=b.ID 
SET a.Total = b.Total
```

Any ideas? the subselect query works on its own.

Comment: A workaround solution is to store the subselect into a "temp" table and join those two. However I would like to know how this could be achieved without using a "temp" table.

Comment: why is a temp table not an option?  Would an update to a permanent table work? that is also an option.  You could also put the sub-select query into a view, depending on what you're tying to accomplish.

Comment: It is an option and this what I currently do. However I would still like to know what is the problem with the above approach.

Comment: So my question could be transposed to' Can I update a table with joining it  with a subselect query?'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `DCount` expression instead of a subquery to do your `UPDATE` ...

```sql
UPDATE table1 a 
SET a.Total = DCount('somevalue', 'ReadsPNPA', '[ID]=' & a.ID);
```

Access `UPDATE` queries are fussy.  Techniques like subqueries or `GROUP BY` cause Access to treat the query as "not updateable".  See [Why is my query read-only?](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html) for more information.

You can use domain aggregate functions (such as `DCount`, `DSum`, `DAvg`, etc.) so that Access will treat the query as updateable.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative  solution  but I avoid to use Access-only functions. ( e.g. Dfunctions) for migration reasons.

Comment: Unfortunately an Access `UPDATE` which joins a subquery will always trigger the same error you're getting now.  If you don't want Access domain functions, put the subquery data into a scratch table and join on that.  However I saw you don't want that, either.  There are no other options.

Comment: Thank you again for confirming that this cannot be achieved this way! Well, I have to use that approach now which is not necessarily bad performance-wise( I think at least). I was just curious if this was possible or not! One last question , narrowing down the problem, is the problem that I use an aggregated function in my subquery or with any subquery the same error would pop? Thank you for you time in advance!

Comment: I think any subquery.  But read what Allen Browne says about this subject in the page I linked.